# How to collect a Verbose stream from a parent-child powershell script from .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have: C#.NET using the PowerShell() object, calling one powershell script, which calls another.

C#->Powershell(parent)->Powershell(child). [capture verbose: parent works, child does not].

My code CORRECTLY grabs/streams Verbose from the first (parent) powershell script. However, I have not been able to get the Verbose stream from the (child) powershell script. Note: if I call hello1.ps directly, it works (because it's not the child).

(I've read numerous articles / searches / other stackoverflow answers. Mostly they talk about how to capture it once, or recommend the `$verbosepreference).

Solutions? Thanks!

```
    public void Run()
    {
        var ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.AddScript("`$verbosepreference='continue'"); // <-- tried this, no effect.
        ps.AddScript("set-location \"" + dir + "\"");
        ps.AddScript(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("./hello-caller.ps1"));
        ps.AddParameter("name", "A");
        ps.AddParameter("where", "B");

        var output = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
        output.DataAdded += Verbose_DataAdded;

        var results = ps.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, output, null, AsyncInvoke, null);
    }

    void Verbose_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        var source = ((PSDataCollection<PSObject>) sender);
        var msg = source[e.Index].ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }

--- hello-caller.ps1 ---
Param(
    [string]$name,
    [string]$where
)

./hello.ps1 $name $where

--- hello.ps1 ---
Param(
    [string]$name,
    [string]$where
)

$i = 0
while ($i -le 30) {
    Write-Verbose "Hello " $name " from " $where
    Start-Sleep -s 1
    $i++
}

return true
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, does it work if you run the child script in the parent scope (. ./hello.ps1 $name $where) ?

Comment: mj: yes, we may have crossed edits, but (see above), when I run it directly, it works just fine. In fact, that was my scenario until I realized I needed to cover child processes - then I saw it failed when I moved it down one level.